# Pass a function as a parameter that may not exist yet in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, undefined

Is it possible to pass a callback function that does not exist yet?  My goal is to have a common function that will wait for another callback function to exist, when it does exist, it should execute it.  This is what I have so far, but I can't figure out how to pass the function in that doesn't exist as a function yet.

```
function RunTemplateFunction(callback, userInfo) {
if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
    callback(userInfo);
} else {
    var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            callback(userInfo);
        }
    }, 200);
}
}
```

I run the function like this:

```
RunTemplateFunction(MyFunctionToRun, GetUserInfo());
```

I get MyFunctionToRun is undefined for obvious reasons, I also tried the workaround of passing the function as a string and then convert the string to a function using eval().  But that throws the same error.  I also thought of using the new function(), but that actually creates a new function.

Any help is appreciated.  thank you.

Comment: Is it possible for you to at least declare the function before calling the `RuntemplateFunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `RunTemplateFunction` by `undefined` there is no way we can see, is callback is defined or not, as we don't have reference to anything.

If you can modify the declaration to accept `object` as below, we can achieve what we want

```
function RunTemplateFunction(options, userInfo) {
    if ($.isFunction(options.callback)) {
        console.log('called1',userInfo);
        options.callback(userInfo);
    } else {
        var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
            if ($.isFunction(options.callback)) {
                console.log('Called dynamically!!');
                clearInterval(myInterval);
                options.callback(userInfo);
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}
var options = {}
RunTemplateFunction(options,{user:122});

options.callback = function(){
 console.log("I'm called!!");
}
```

This will print

```
Called dynamically!!
I'm called!!
```

**EDIT:**

We can also call `callback` function in following way without `setInterval`, it will look different but `options.callback` variable is replaced by `template.callMe` function and its instantaneous also.

```
function TemplateRunner(userInfo){
  this.callMe = function(cb){
    this.templateFunction(cb);
  }
  this.templateFunction = function(callback){
   callback(userInfo);
  }
}
var template = new TemplateRunner({user:100})
template.callMe(function(user){
  console.log('call me1',user);
});
template.callMe(function(user){
  console.log('call me2',user);
})
```

This will print

```
call me1 {user: 100}
call me2 {user: 100}
```

Comment: thanks for the response - I can test tonight and update.

Comment: I did test this, and it does work - I'll keep this technique in my back pocket for sure.  However, I need to run multiple functions this way that are loaded from within a handful of script bundles.  So basically they would just keep overwriting options.callback.  I'd almost need to store the functions in a list object, but then I think I'm back at square one with code needed to decide which function I'm trying to run.  If you have any other good ideas please share!